# How to create my own Linux distro (say from ubuntu source code)?

Tags: linux

I wish to create my own Linux distribution (not editing linux kernel) from an existing OS like Ubuntu. To be specific, I wish to have my Linux distro from Ubuntu source code. I am planning to change the way the Ubuntu desktop looks. (E.g. I wish to pop up TimeTable when clicking the date in the desktop).

How can I do that?

Comment: *There is no such thing as "Ubuntu source code".*  There is also no such thing as "the Ubuntu desktop".  There are are a variety of desktop environments used on ubuntu, I think the current default is Unity, also very popular: GNOME, KDE, Xfce...they can all be customized, but they are not the same.  Which one are you referring to?

Comment: You aren't looking to _create your own distro_; rather, you want to customize Ubuntu and add your changes.

Answer (score 6):

There is no "Ubuntu source code". Ubuntu is a collection of programs configured in a certain way. You need to identify the individual program that you want to change.

You don't need to create a new operating system to do this, in fact, what you want to modify has nothing at all to do with Linux, and everything to do with your desktop environment (the default on Ubuntu is [Unity](http://unity.ubuntu.com/)).

You may or may not need to modify the Unity source to implement what you want (it seems likely that you wouldn't have to, anyway), as I don't know Unity well enough to say. Whether you have to modify the Unity source or not, your answer is not in the Linux sources as they do not handle what you're wanting to modify.

Answer (score 5):

I guess you meant to `customize Ubuntu`, it's like a different look (by change the default `gtk2/3` theme), and adding more favorite apps.

Take a look at the [official guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DerivativeDistroHowto), it will teach you how to create a new LiveCD base on the original Ubuntu

But for the time table stuff, you need to program a bit, make your own indicator widget, adding the auto start, etc. That could take few minutes.

Comment: Haha, overconfidence... :) This site is so serious and that is good, but you made me laugh alright. But to be serious once again, that advice about the LiveCD may be confusing as the OP might think he needs to do that just to configure his desktop. There is no mention he uses or wishes a boot CD.